# Is It Allowed to Assign popup_create() To a Variable?

Tags: vimscript, popup

I know it returns the window ID, but when I run the function that does what's on the question title, it keeps telling me that a 'List is required'. I don't know what's going on.

```
" Check the type of issue and add the appropriate message
if correction.rule.issueType == 'misspelling'
  let content = 'Did you mean: ' . join(map(correction.replacements, 'v:val.value'), ', ')
endif

" Set the popup's option
let options = {'border': 'none', 'line': 1, 'col': 1, 'minwidth': &columns, 'title': correction.message}

" Display the popup
let popup = popup_create('Hello world!', options)
```

I've tried changing the variable name to `popup_message` but that still resulted in the same thing. I've tried testing it first in the command line, and it worked with an empty dictionary for the `options`. That's why I'm led to believe that it may not be allowed to be assigned to a variable. I've also tried modifying the options to non-variables as value.

Comment: As usual, you are making huge diagnostic mistakes. You should probably focus on those instead of writing code you don't understand. You are **supposed** to assign to a variable if you ever hope to interact with that object programmatically. That is not at all where your problem comes from. It comes from not reading :help popup_create-arguments with the attention it deserves.

Comment: Hm, the popup is still drawn, even so there was an error message. I don't think this is supposed to happen

Comment: Oh. It's the border. Sorry, @romainl.

Comment: Yes, border is supposed to be a list.

Comment: I'll read carefully next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comments: the error message is about the function arguments (you can always `:help EXXX` with the error code you get). Specifically, `popup_create` expects `options.border` to be a list.

There’s a small bug in that this doesn’t stop the popup from being created, which is confusing.

Comment: *There’s a small bug in that this doesn’t stop the popup from being created, which is confusing.*

I have addressed that https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/12711